# how to count of the number of filled cells in a column in an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, count

So I'm currently trying to get a count of the number of filled cells in a column in an excel sheet, but I'm unsure as to how to do that. I've seen things like:

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

but that doesn't give an actual count. Does anyone know how to get an integer valued count? Are there any methods built into excel for that purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counta function could work.

```
'If the data is in column A
Dim lngCount as Long
lngCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
msgbox lngCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop throught the cells range, I wonder which method is faster - this or using Excel's CountA (below would go into almost infinite loop if `r` range is the whole column):

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Range
Dim c As Long

Set r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each x In r
   If Not r = "" Then
      c = c + 1
   End If
Next r

MsgBox r

End Sub
```

Comment: In my experience it is usually more performant to use Excel's built in functions/functionality than to bring data from Excel into a VBA script (especially if multiple calls to excel are made to retrieve the data).    Range.Value2 is a way to get back an array of values into a vba object in one call.